# Jackson Serialising of object's fields varying with the order of fields declaration in Object

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jackson

I am observing a weird issue. If `recon_orders` is placed before `orders` it's able to serialise the fields. But if I reverse the order of `recon_orders` and `orders`, it is giving only id in the `order_items` not the complete object of `order_items` (in recon_orders)!

```
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SomeDto {

    @JsonProperty("recon_orders")
    private List<OrderListingDto> reconOrders;

    @JsonProperty("orders")
    private List<OrderListingDto> orders;

    //... some other fields  

}
```

With recon_orders above, o/p

```
"recon_orders": [
    {
      "adjustable": false,
      "billable": false,
      "id": 1,
      "order_items": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "isActive": true,
          "inventoryItemId": null,
          "quantity": 1,
          "listPrice": 100.0,
          "price": 100.0,
          "processingDate": null,
          "totalAmount": 100.0,
          "status": null,
          "itemType": "EARLY_MOVEOUT_PENALTY",
          "totalDiscountAmount": null,
          "isRecurring": false,
          "totalTaxAmount": null,
          "chargeType": "CHARGE",
          "category": "EARLY_MOVEOUT_PENALTY",
          "description": "test",
          "owed": true,
          "discount": false,
          "payment": false,
          "orderId": 1
        }
      ],
    }
  ]
```

with `orders` above `recon_orders`

```
  "recon_orders": [
    {
      "adjustable": false,
      "billable": false,
      "id": 1,
      "order_items": [
        1
      ],
    }
  ]
```

What could be the problem here? (maybe JsonBackReference or some other technical annotation deep in the OrderItems). Also recon_orders is a subset of orders.
Spring version : 2.0.2.RELEASE
jackson version : 2.9.9

Comment: Please update the question with deserialization code

Comment: I didnt fully understand 'deserialization code' ? Spring is doing it with the help of Jackson library . Also the o/p is same if I use the ObjectMapper::writeValueAsString

Comment: Ok, worth updating the question with OrderListingDto and orser_items code